# source command not working in Ubuntu 20.04, complains about missing directory

Tags: command-line, 20.04, environment-variables

I'm trying to reinstall openssl library on Ubuntu 20.04 according to https://docs.openiam.com/docs-4.2.1.3/appendix/2-openssl and I'm stuck at the last step.

I have to reload the environment variables, but it's not working:

```
letho@ubuntu:/$ source /etc/environment
bash: :/usr/local/ssl/bin: No such file or directory
letho@ubuntu:/$ sudo source /etc/environment
sudo: source: command not found
letho@ubuntu:/$ sudo -s
root@ubuntu:/# source /etc/environment
bash: :/usr/local/ssl/bin: No such file or directory
```

I'm afraid I might have touched something wrong trying to solve the problem: `libssl.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: Please add the output of `cat /etc/environment` ... `:/usr/local/ssl/bin` seems to be dangling alone in that file while it shouldn't .

Comment: here it goes
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"
:/usr/local/ssl/bin

Comment: Make it `PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/local/ssl/bin"` ... One line.

Answer (score 1):

Check the output of `cat /etc/environment` ... `:/usr/local/ssl/bin` seems to be dangling alone outside the quoted assignment string for the environment variable `PATH` in that file while it shouldn't ... e.g. something like this:

```
 $ cat /etc/environment
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin" :/usr/local/ssl/bin
```

Edit that file and put `:/usr/local/ssl/bin` inside the quotes like so:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/local/ssl/bin"
```

Then, save the file and it should work.